# Adobe Reader Parameters

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, process, adobe

Im trying to save a pdf file as a new pdf but printting it (*required*), Im using Adobe Acrobat to do that cause it brings me the option to introduce parameters.
The thing is : I need to do it silently (*Not a single Window can been saw*). So I need to set a printer, a path to my file and an output destination.
As I said I need to "print it" as a new pdf so I'm using Microsoft Print to PDF to do that (I don't know if it is the better option).

Thank you so much!

```
            string file = name;
            string pathFile = "C:\\DfPrinter\\" + name;
            ProcessStartInfo infoPrintPdf = new ProcessStartInfo(); 

               
string printerName = "Microsoft Print to PDF";
                infoPrintPdf.FileName = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Adobe\\Acrobat Reader DC\\Reader\\AcroRd32.exe";
                infoPrintPdf.Arguments = string.Format("/t" + " '" + pathFile + "'" +"' "  +"'"+printerName+"'");
                infoPrintPdf.CreateNoWindow = true;
                infoPrintPdf.UseShellExecute = false;
                infoPrintPdf.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                Process printPdf = new Process();
                printPdf.StartInfo = infoPrintPdf;
                printPdf.Start();

          

  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);

       

 if (!printPdf.CloseMainWindow())              
            printPdf.Kill(); printPdf.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Acrobat Reader can print silently, but you could consider using the [Win2PDF "printpdf" command line](https://www.win2pdf.com/doc/command-line-print-pdf.html):

```
win2pdfd.exe printpdf "filename.pdf" Win2PDF "newfilename.pdf"
```

This prints the PDF silently to a new PDF specified by "newfilename" by using the Win2PDF printer.